# Python: Ending line every N characters when writing to text file

Tags: python

I am reading the webpage at "https://google.com" and writing as a string to a notepad file.  In the notepad file, I want to break and make a newline every N characters while writing, so that I don't have to scroll horizontally in notepad.  I have looked up a number of solutions but none of them do this so far.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
webfile = page.readlines()

with open("file01.txt", 'w') as f:
   for line in webfile:
       f.write(str(line))

f.close()
```

Comment: Notepad has a wordwrap function

Comment: i'd do `char_cnr= 0` `if char_cnr== n : cha_cnr =0, print("\n")` i dont know if my syntax are correct in python but you get the idea

Comment: @Manu Well played sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better yet, use the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/textwrap.html) library.  Then you can use

```
textwrap.fill(str(line))
```

and get breaks on whitespace and other useful additions.

Answer (score 0):

This will split each line at 100 characters:

```
for line in webfile:
    while len(line) > 100:
        # split the line
        f.write(line[:100])  # write the first 100 characters
        f.write('\n')        # write the newline character
        line = line[100:]    # remember the remainder of the line
    f.write(str(line))
```

Comment: You mean `line = line[100:]` instead of `list = list[100:]`, right?

Comment: @dkasak Exactly :) Fixed it.